# Circular relationships with Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes

```
@Entity
public class Auditable {
    @Id
    long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    Audit a;
    ......
}

@Entity
public class Actor extends Auditable {
....
}

@Entity
public class AnotherEntity extends Auditable {
.....
}


@Entity
public class Audit {
    @Id
    long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    Actor b;
.....
}
```

Every record in the database has a reference to an 'Audit' object. The audit object has a reference to the actor who created the audit. Since an actor can be created/modified it also has a reference to an Audit.

Hence a circular dependency.

Hibernate doesn't like this

Hibernate fails with the following error:

> Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need to visualize how the db model should look like? ManyToOne on both sides look really werid

Comment: Show the code for persisting. Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Manualy set IDs before persisting both objects.